# Difference between closing a socket and closing a network stream (System.Net.Sockets)

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server, tcpclient

I have a proxy server implemented, after sending the final response to client if I directly close the socket (System.Net.Sockets TCPClient.Client.Close()) then client end receives connection aborted error but instead if I use System.Net.Sockets TCPClient.getStream().Close(), it works successfully.I want to understand what's the difference and why is client side receiving an error in the first scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that Close of sockets is not trivial operation as most people think :)
First of all, you should understand the how the close should be done correctly. Basically, you have to consider that close is a kind of message like any other message sent out your socket. Or other words close() is an information on the other side of communication that the peer finished some kind of work.
Now the important thing to understand that having a TCP socket you can inform the peer that you finished sending or finished listening.
On this page, you can check out how it works in the background (note that ACK and FIN are IP layer messages so even using plain sockets implementation you will never see them): http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm

So now the more practical step. Please consider that you have a client and server. The server needs to receive a message and close the connection. Please consider that client is just going to send a message and then closes the connection. If you will also consider that networks need some time to process your communication, you will realize that if you do it quickly, client will close the connection before server received your message. If you can the TCPClient.Client.Close() client will stop listening for anything (that means also for information about that the server closed the connection). So here comes the TCP stack to play (windows does it for you) - in case you will close this way the socket, TCP stack, needs to inform the server site that whatever server has sent goes to dump. So that's why you have an exception.

So the correct way is to:

1. inform the server that client finished sending any data (FIN)
2. wait until server confirms that he knows that client will not send any data (ACK)
3. now server should inform client that will stop sending data (FIN)
4. now the client can say - "ok I got it, I will not listen anymore" (ACK)

Anyway, the C# TCPClient seems to hide the logic of the background socket closing routine, but if you will not call the close sequence correct way, you'll end up with errors.

I hope that this little bit long explanation will help you understand how it works in the background and finally let you understand why.

It's also a good way to read more about TCP protocol details if you wish to learn more: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPTransmissionControlProtocolTCP.htm

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in order to close connection, you need to send some special bytes sequence. And looks like it is implemented only by tcpclient library , and not implemented by socket library. Probably something like Eof should be sent.
You may check it by some net traffic utilities like tcpdump.
Good luck!